# Plugging array into nonlinear equation

Tags: python, arrays

I am very new to Python... and I am having a hard time plugging the contents of my 1d array into a nonlinear equation so I can ultimately plot the results. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readfiles(file_list):
    """ read <TAB> delemited files as strings
        ignoring '# Comment' lines """
    data = []
    for fname in file_list:
        data.append(
                    np.genfromtxt(fname,
                                  comments='#',    # skip comment lines
                                  delimiter='\t',
                                  dtype ="|S", autostrip=True).T)
    return data

data = readfiles(['CR1000_rawMeasurements_15m.txt'])

def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]

x = column(data,18)

for i in x:
    thermTemp1_degC = 1/(1.401E-3 + 2.377E-4*np.log(i) + 9.730E-8*np.log(i)**3)-273.15
```

All I have been successfully able to do is extract the column I need from my data. When I run this script, I get 'TypeError: Not implemented for this type.' (my 1d array, x, is just a column of zeros right now.) How can I fix this?

Comment: It's difficult to help without an example of the data. It sounds like it could be bad data that's causing your problem. As a side note, you are re-assigning thermTemp1_degC each loop iteration, this means at the end of the loop it will just have the value associated with the last element in the vector x. Also, if x is a numpy array you don't need a loop, just replace each `i` with `x` in that line, take it out of a for loop and that should work.

Comment: '[array(['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
      dtype='|S19')]'

Comment: Sorry. This is the current form that my data is in. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Yes, you need something like this array([0, 0, 0, 0]). Yours appears to be characters rather than numbers. This seems to be a problem with your readfiles function. Have you tried using numpy.loadtxt? It should do everything you need.

Comment: I'm working on it  now! I'm having a hard time loading the date as a string and the data as floats.

Comment: Ok I can help with that, I'll put this stuff in an answer. Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: 2. I actually figured it out, I just imported my dates as floats instead. I'll fix it later when I plot. Now, I am just trying to isolate the column with my data so I can plug it in to the equation, but python keeps on giving me row one instead of column one. I can't win!

Comment: If it's a multidimensional array just use data[:, i] where i is the column you want. You can convert python lists to numpy arrays using data = np.array(data).

Comment: Yes, I've tried that! But that just returns the first array instead of the second column in each array. My data looks like this: 
[[[ 737055.       0.]
  [ 737055.       0.]
  [ 737055.       0.]
  [ 737055.       0.]
  [ 737055.       0.]
  [ 735773.       0.]
  [ 735773.       0.]
  [ 735773.       0.]]]

Comment: I've stated putting this stuff in an answer, given the example data in your comment I think I have a solution for returning the right column.

Comment: Great! If the answer is helpful please upvote it (the up arrow next to the answer). If you think it answers the question please consider "accepting" it (the check mark next to the answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points to address here.

## Returning the Correct Column

The array you've given in the comments is a little strange, but you can retrieve the columns with numpy:

```
data = [[ 737055., 0.], [ 737055., 0.], [ 737055., 0.], [ 737055., 0.], [ 737055., 0.], [ 735773., 0.], [ 735773., 0.], [ 735773., 0.]]]

data
=> [[[737055.0, 0.0],
     [737055.0, 0.0],
     [737055.0, 0.0],
     [737055.0, 0.0],
     [737055.0, 0.0],
     [735773.0, 0.0],
     [735773.0, 0.0],
     [735773.0, 0.0]]]

column_0 = np.array(data)[0][:, 0]
column_1 = np.array(data)[0][:, 1]

column_0
=> array([ 737055.,  737055.,  737055.,  737055.,  737055.,  735773.,
           735773.,  735773.])

column_1
=> array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

## Performing the Calculation

As `x` is a numpy array (if you use the above column code) you don't need to put this in a for loop:

```
thermTemp1_degC = 1/(1.401E-3 + 2.377E-4*np.log(i) + 9.730E-8*np.log(i)**3)-273.15
```

Here `thermTemp1_degC` is a numpy array the same size as `x`.